# C#: Perform Operations on GPU, not CPU (Calculate Pi)

Tags: c#, .net, api, gpu

I've recently read a lot about software (mostly scientific/math and encryption related) that moves part of their calculation onto the GPU which causes a 100-1000 (!) fold increase in speed for supported operations.

Is there a library, API or other way to run something on the GPU via C#? I'm thinking of simple Pi calculation. I have a GeForce 8800 GTX if that's relevant at all (would prefer card independent solution though).

Comment: I don't think you need the GPU for a "simple Pi calculation" unless you're doing it thousands of times a second...

Comment: It's not about 'needing' it. I just suggested it as a proof of concept example.

Comment: I really liked multiple answers, including CUDA, CUDA.NET, Accellerator, Brahma and OpenCL. So FYI for everybody who looks at this question later - take a look at all the answers.

Comment: @Alex as far as i know you can not do it in c# you need to know 7/10 c++, all the libraries(cudafy,aleagpu,...) are just invokers for c++ codes

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a very new technology, but you might investigate [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).  Since your question is tagged with C#, here is a [.Net wrapper](http://www.cass-hpc.com/solutions/libraries/cuda-net/cuda-net-archive).

As a bonus, it appears that your 8800 GTX supports CUDA.

Comment: Your link for the wrapper is dead.

Comment: @Alizter - Thanks. I did a search and plugged in a new URL, if people are looking for it.

Comment: Use Alea GPU from www.quantalea.com. It is a full fledged .NET to CUDA compiler, cross platform with very good developer support for debugging and profiling.

Answer (score 16):

Another option that hasn't been mentioned for GPU calculation from C# is [Brahma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/).

[Brahma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/) provides a LINQ-based abstraction for GPU calculations - it's basically LINQ to GPU.  It works over OpenGL and DirectX without extra libraries (but requires SM3).  Some of the samples are fairly amazing.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375011/utilizing-the-gpu-with-c)

You're probably looking for [Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/), but if you are interested in game development in general I'll suggest you take a look at XNA

Comment: I had not heard of this one - interesting!  I worry that it's still a research project though.  Is it ready for commercial applications?

Comment: To be perfectly honest I haven't tried it out and I don't know how stable it is. I do some graphics programming and had it in my bookmarks for future reference, and it seemed to be easier to approach than CUDA for this problem.

Comment: I've got an ATI card so maybe I'll give Accelerator a try.

Answer (score 4):

[CUDA.NET](http://www.cass-hpc.com/solutions/libraries/cuda-net/)  should be exactly what you're looking for, and it seems to support your specific graphics card.

Comment: Your link for CUDA.net is DEAD too.

Answer (score 4):

You can access the latest Direct3D APIs from .NET using the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). Direct3D 11 comes with Compute Shaders. These are roughly comparable to CUDA, but work also on non-NVIDIA GPUs.

Note that Managed DirectX and XNA are limited to the Direct3D 9 feature set, which is somewhat difficult to use for GPGPU.

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of .Net bindings for Nvidia's CUDA api, it's called [CUDA.net](http://www.gass-ltd.co.il/en/products/cuda.net/). You can refer to the [reference guide](http://www.gass-ltd.co.il/files/cuda.net/CUDA.NET_1.1_beta3.pdf) to look at some sample C# code.

The preferred way to access your co-proccesor (GPU) would be using [OpenCL](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/) so that your code would be portable with ATI cards, but I believe there may be additional coding required and I'm not sure how much support OpenCL has for the .Net platform.

If you want to use C++, [here's a quick overview](http://llpanorama.wordpress.com/2008/05/21/my-first-cuda-program/) on how to get some sample code compiling with Visual Studio.

Comment: CUDA.net Link is DEAD

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Accelerator (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/) was working great for a couple of tests.