# Java multithreading without main method

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java.I have a function where I want the function to execute a multithreaded behaviour.The problem is that I will be making the jar without main method inside it.. Just wanted to know that can we have a multithreaded function in Java without a class having main method ?? 
I have the following code and I want this "myHandler" function to have multithreaded behaviour such that whenever this function gets called,different threads execute it...Can you please help me this code executing multithreaded behaviour??  Thank You

```
public String myHandler(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent,Context context)
{
    int singleRecord=0;
    long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    //LambdaLogger lambdaLogger=context.getLogger();
     for(KinesisEventRecord rec : kinesisEvent.getRecords())
     {
         singleRecord=0;
         System.out.println("Kinesis Record inside is:"+new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
         //count++;
         singleRecord++;
         //  System.out.println(new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
     }
     count=count+singleRecord;
     long endtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
     long totaltime = endtime-starttime;
     time=time+totaltime;
     System.out.println("Time required to execute single Lambda function for "+singleRecord+" records is"+" :: "+totaltime+" milliseconds");
     System.out.println("Total time required to execute Lambda function for "+count+" records is"+" :: "+time+" milliseconds");
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Put it in a `Thread`.

Comment: Yes, you can cerate a class that spawns new threads, and put that class in a jar file that does not have a main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is exactly what you want but you could do something like this:

```
public String myHandler(final KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, final Context context)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int singleRecord=0;
            long starttime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            //LambdaLogger lambdaLogger=context.getLogger();
            for(KinesisEventRecord rec : kinesisEvent.getRecords())
            {
                singleRecord=0;
                System.out.println("Kinesis Record inside is:"+new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
                //count++;
                singleRecord++;
                //  System.out.println(new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
            }
            count=count+singleRecord;
            long endtime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totaltime = endtime-starttime;
            time=time+totaltime;
            System.out.println("Time required to execute single Lambda function for "+singleRecord+" records is"+" :: "+totaltime+" milliseconds");
            System.out.println("Total time required to execute Lambda function for "+count+" records is"+" :: "+time+" milliseconds");
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

This code will start your code in a new thread once you call the method but any parameters you want to use in the thread have to be declared `final` to be visible in the anonymous implementation of `Runnable`.

Another solution would be to create a new class and extend the `Thread` class:

```
public class MyHandlerThread extends Thread {
    KinesisEvent kinesisEvent;
    Context context;

    public MyHandlerThread(KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, Context context) {
        super();
        this.kinesisEvent = kinesisEvent;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int singleRecord = 0;
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //LambdaLogger lambdaLogger=context.getLogger();
        for (KinesisEventRecord rec : kinesisEvent.getRecords()) {
            singleRecord = 0;
            System.out.println("Kinesis Record inside is:" + new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
            //count++;
            singleRecord++;
            //  System.out.println(new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
        }
        count = count + singleRecord;
        long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totaltime = endtime - starttime;
        time = time + totaltime;
        System.out.println("Time required to execute single Lambda function for " + singleRecord + " records is" + " :: " + totaltime + " milliseconds");
        System.out.println("Total time required to execute Lambda function for " + count + " records is" + " :: " + time + " milliseconds");
    }

}
```

In order to start this as a thread you have to create an instance of the object and call its start method.

```
MyHandlerThread thread = new MyHandlerThread(param1, param2);
thread.start();
```

Hope this helps (:

Comment: Thank You for helping me with the solution...I tried all the approaches of multi-threading..But I want to know that whenever I execute the code as single-threaded it works much faster whereas whenever I make that code as multi-threaded it gives me slow performance...What can I do so that whenever I execute code with multithreaded approach,it works faster ??

Comment: @Akki Well... performance improvements using threads depend on a lot of things. For example on what kind of  CPU your code runs  and how many threads you are using. Maybe this can help you a little:  [Performance with multiple threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292626/does-multi-threading-improve-performance-how)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information...that was quite useful & understandable..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If method should always be executed in separate thread, you can create a Thread, and call your code from that thread by following way:

```
    public String myHandler(final KinesisEvent kinesisEvent, final Context context) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int singleRecord = 0;
                long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //LambdaLogger lambdaLogger=context.getLogger();
                for (KinesisEventRecord rec : kinesisEvent.getRecords()) {
                    singleRecord = 0;
                    System.out.println("Kinesis Record inside is:" + new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
                    //count++;
                    singleRecord++;
                    //  System.out.println(new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
                }
                count = count + singleRecord;
                long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long totaltime = endtime - starttime;
                time = time + totaltime;
                System.out.println("Time required to execute single Lambda function for " + singleRecord + " records is" + " :: " + totaltime + " milliseconds");
                System.out.println("Total time required to execute Lambda function for " + count + " records is" + " :: " + time + " milliseconds");
                return null;
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for helping me with the solution...I tried all the approaches of multi-threading..But I want to know that whenever I execute the code as single-threaded it works much faster whereas whenever I make that code as multi-threaded it gives me slow performance...What can I do so that whenever I execute code with multithreaded approach,it works faster ??