# QuickSort performs worse with more threads

Tags: java, multithreading, quicksort

I'm learning about threads in java and I was trying to run QuickSort using two threads on one array, but didn't work as expected . The idea is to run one thread on the first part after the array's partition, and the second thread would run on the other part. I assumed using two threads running in parallel would improve the performance, but it didn't. After many tests, using the two threads was relatively worse than the regular original quicksort sorting.

I don't know what seems to be the problem.

Comment: see [Does multi-threading improve performance? How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292626/does-multi-threading-improve-performance-how). How many cores do you have ? And is the question correct ? It seems to work only not so fast in this case

Comment: I'm wondering how you benchmarked it? With 50 elements?! Did you read about how to do a proper micro-benchmark in Java? Have you heard about the Fork-Join framework of Java?

Comment: @pirho I've a Core i3 processor (dual core).

Comment: @AKSW The QuickSort works as same as the one in CLRS, where the pivot is the last element. I've read about Fork-Join framework, but is it the only way to use multiple threads in java ?

Answer (score 1):

If I see correctly, you are using `Thread.run()` instead of `Thread.start()` to execute a thread (i.e. you should use `tUpper.start()` and `tLower.start()` in your code). Only the second method creates a new thread. First one does not - the method is executed in the calling thread.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674174/what-is-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-thread-run) question.