# Coding CUDA with C#?

Tags: c#, cuda

I've been looking for some information on coding CUDA (the nvidia gpu language) with C#.  I have seen a few of the libraries, but it seems that they would add a bit of overhead (because of the p/invokes, etc).

- How should I go about using CUDA in my C# applications?  Would it be better to code it in say C++ and compile that into a dll?
- Would this overhead of using a wrapper kill any advantages I would get from using CUDA?
- And are there any good examples of using CUDA with C#?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is such a nice complete cuda 4.2 wrapper as [**ManagedCuda**](http://kunzmi.github.io/managedCuda/).
You simply add C++ cuda project to your solution, which contains yours c# project, then you just add

```
call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "$(ProjectDir)Kernels\*.cu"') do nvcc -ptx -arch sm_21 -m 64 -o "$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\%%~na_64.ptx" "$(ProjectDir)Kernels\%%~na.cu"
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b "$(ProjectDir)Kernels\*.cu"') do nvcc -ptx -arch sm_21 -m 32 -o "$(ProjectDir)bin\Debug\%%~na.ptx" "$(ProjectDir)Kernels\%%~na.cu"
```

to post-build events in your c# project properties, this compiles *.ptx file and copies it in your c# project output directory.

Then you need simply create new context, load module from file, load function and work with device.

```
//NewContext creation
CudaContext cntxt = new  CudaContext();

//Module loading from precompiled .ptx in a project output folder
CUmodule cumodule = cntxt.LoadModule("kernel.ptx");

//_Z9addKernelPf - function name, can be found in *.ptx file
CudaKernel addWithCuda = new CudaKernel("_Z9addKernelPf", cumodule, cntxt);

//Create device array for data
CudaDeviceVariable<cData2> vec1_device = new CudaDeviceVariable<cData2>(num);            

//Create arrays with data
cData2[] vec1 = new cData2[num];

//Copy data to device
vec1_device.CopyToDevice(vec1);

//Set grid and block dimensions                       
addWithCuda.GridDimensions = new dim3(8, 1, 1);
addWithCuda.BlockDimensions = new dim3(512, 1, 1);

//Run the kernel
addWithCuda.Run(
    vec1_device.DevicePointer, 
    vec2_device.DevicePointer, 
    vec3_device.DevicePointer);

//Copy data from device
vec1_device.CopyToHost(vec1);
```

Comment: How much of overhead will this be?
I need to call one of my CUDA kernels repeatedly in a for loop in the host code.

Comment: ManagedCuda unfortunately no longer appears to be active.

Answer (score 16):

This has been commented on the nvidia list in the past:

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=97729

it would be easy to use P/Invoke to use it in assemblies like so:

```
  [DllImport("nvcuda")]
  public static extern CUResult cuMemAlloc(ref CUdeviceptr dptr, uint bytesize);
```

Comment: I didn't realise that you could just PInvoke the CUDA calls. Shame that you need to buy into NVidia for this to work.

Comment: Will this have less overhead? I think the managed CUDA version above should have overhead due to marshalling/unmarshalling of the data?

Answer (score 7):

I guess Hybridizer, explained [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/hybridizer-csharp/) as a blog post on Nvidia is also worth to mention. [Here](https://github.com/altimesh/hybridizer-basic-samples) is its related GitHub repo it seems.

**Update 1**

**[Altimesh Hybridizer](https://developer.nvidia.com/altimesh-hybridizer)** is an advanced productivity tool that generates vectorized C++ source code (AVX) and CUDA C source code from .NET assemblies (MSIL) or Java archives (java bytecode).
[image]
In managed development environments, developers can use virtual functions and generics, yet make efficient use of the GPU's compute capabilities, with ~80% usage of peak performance of processors and memory. From a single version of the source code, developers can debug and execute on both CPU and CUDA GPU, within your favorite development environment, by stepping into original source code (.NET or Java). Applications can be profiled using state of the art solutions such as VTUNE  and Nsight,  referencing locations in the original source code.

**Key features**

- Source code generation from Java or .NET binaries (Java bytecode / MSIL bytecode)
- Full debugging /profiling integration with NVIDIA Nsight for Visual Studio Edition
- Support of virtual functions, generics – mapped onto C++ templates for optimal performances
- Single version of the input targeting GPU and CPU with near-optimal performance (automatic vectorization)
- Code generation agnostic of operating system: e.g. develop in dot net on windows, debug GPU code in Nsight Visual Studio Edition, deploy on linux in a Java system
- Non-intrusive environment: Hybridizer is attribute/annotations based, hence the solution will still run without it, probably slower

**Hybridizer comes in two versions:**

- Hybridizer Software Suite: enables CUDA, AVX, AVX2, AVX512 targets and outputs source code. This source code can be reviewed, which is mandatory in some businesses such as investment banks. Hybridizer Software Suite is licensed per customer [upon request](http://www.altimesh.com/contact/).
- [Hybridizer Essentials](http://www.altimesh.com/hybridizer-essentials/): enables only the CUDA target and outputs only binaries. Hybridizer Essentials is a free Visual Studio extension with no hardware restrictions. [You can find a set of basic code samples and educational material on GitHub](https://github.com/altimesh/hybridizer-basic-samples). These samples also serve as a way to reproduce our performance results.

Comment: All the update section is coming from @Lakshitha's edit and it's attribution goes to them, so I should say here, thanks for the comprehensive edit, really appreciated, guess however you can leave your complementary edits as a separate answer the next time, but in this case, as the author I've no other option than accepting you awesome edit, thanks 

Answer (score 5):

There are several alternatives you can use to use CUDA in your C# applications.

- Write a C++/CUDA library in a separate project, and use P/Invoke. The overhead of P/invokes over native calls will likely be negligible.
- Use a CUDA wrapper such as [ManagedCuda](http://kunzmi.github.io/managedCuda/)(which will expose entire CUDA API). You won't have to write your DLLImports by hand for the entire CUDA runtime API (which is convenient). Unfortunely, you will still have to write your own CUDA code in a separate project.
- (**recommended**) You can use free/opensource/proprietary compilers (which will generate cuda (either source or binary) from your c# code.

You can find several of them online : have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375011/utilizing-the-gpu-with-c-sharp) for example.

Comment: Good options but I just want to point out that sometime you can't use a different or proprietary compiler.