# GPU (Nvidia) accelerated saving of JPEGs

Tags: c#, gpu, nvidia

I have a C# app that captures 30fps of live video a 1080p camera. For internal processing purposes it is saving each captured frame as in-memory JPEG but this is taking a severe toll on the CPU.

Is there a known way to offload the JPEG saving to a Nvidia GPU?

I can take any solution including C++, P/Invoke as long as the performance is improved.

Comment: Try the suggestions at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375011/utilizing-the-gpu-with-c-sharp

Comment: Have you tried http://bit.ly/TLXWr4 ? What I mean is that there are several GPU accelerated libraries on the first Google page. Since the question is "Is there a known way to offload the JPEG saving to a Nvidia GPU?" you obviously haven't even done a simple Google search on the subject.

Comment: Even though I find your comment helpful, the tone is unacceptable. Why do you assume I must be familiar with "CUDA" which is the term you used in your search? And **yes**, I did do a lot of searching before asking for help. I always do. You assume too much. But still thanks for the help.