# Testing the Q# code on a real quantum computer?

Tags: quantum-computing, q#

I am using the Microsoft Quantum Development Kit for Python. Can I run the code on a real quantum computer?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: you might be interested in knowing that there is now a dedicated quantum computing stackexchange site: [quantumcomputing.SE](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Earlier this week we have [announced Azure Quantum](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/quantum/2019/11/04/announcing-microsoft-azure-quantum/) - a full-stack cloud ecosystem that includes several hardware backends. With it you'll be able to run your Q# code on simulators, resource estimators and actual hardware in a uniform manner.

At the moment Azure Quantum is in private preview; you can request to be an early adopter [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/quantum).

---

Alternatively, you can whip up some infrastructure code to use Q# to control your own quantum computer, as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801787/is-it-possible-to-use-q-to-control-my-own-quantum-computer).