# How to avoid binary copies using operator overloading on struct types?

Tags: c#

I have a struct called Vector2D. I use struct here to benefit from value types instead of references to instances, because vectors are intense with graphics generally. Last thing I want is thousands of vectors doing binary copies. Since the class just uses two floats (64 bits, then), it's not much of a concern, but I want to learn about this anyway.

I'd like to use operator overloading on my Vector2D struct. I'm worried this does at least three binary copies then: 1 binary copy with 'new', 2 binary copies passing in v1 and v2.

```
public static Vector2D operator +(Vector2D v1, Vector2D v2)
{
    return new Vector2D(v1.m_x + v2.m_x, v1.m_y + v2.m_y);
}
```

Is there a different way to make this more efficient for structs?

Comment: Being copied by value is the nature of structs, isn't it? I don't think you can improve this any further. And remember, premature optimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: In C++ you can pass the reference of a structure with operator overloading. This seems to be not be the case with C#. I'm a little surprised, although 'in' helps with larger structs.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 7.2 you can avoid most of copying using `in` modifier.

```
public struct Vector2D
{
    double m_x;
    double m_y;

    public Vector2D(in double m_x, in double m_y)
    {
        this.m_x = m_x;
        this.m_y = m_y;
    }

    public static Vector2D operator +(in Vector2D v1, in Vector2D v2)
    {
        return new Vector2D(v1.m_x + v2.m_x, v1.m_y + v2.m_y);
    }
}
```

Make sure in your project settings you are using C# latest minor version and you are also running latest visual studio update. (goto project settings => build => advanced => choose language version)

`in` is like `ref` with a twist that is `in` parameters are readonly.

so you are passing `v1` and `v2` by reference without copying them. this is more helpful for larger structs. for small structs like yours I don't think it performs much better.

by the way I think there are better tools to manipulate vectors faster using GPU. I haven't done that my self but maybe look here and try it your self.

[Utilizing the GPU with csharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375011/utilizing-the-gpu-with-c-sharp)

Comment: Passing very small structs with `in` is actually slower than passing them by value. This is because 64/32bit value can be easily passed via register or pushed on to the stack. With references you have to copy reference by value and then load value of this reference. `in` was mostly designed for big structs where passing 64/32 bit reference is better than copying e.g. > 256 bit struct.